# Can't configure ADDITIONAL section in a BIND 9.8 authoritative DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, authoritative

Glue records are supposed to be configured in the registrar when the DNS server hostname belongs to the same domain.

It is not exactly my case because I am setting up the DNS server for a domain 'example.com' while the name servers can be resolved using another domain 'mydnsprovider.com'.

Nevertheless, to facilitate and allow the automatic configuration of the glue records in the registrar, I would like to include the A records for the nameservers 'ns1.mydnsprovider.com' like 'additional' records, like this:

```
; Zone file for example.com
$TTL    3600
example.com.       IN      SOA     example.com.    admin.example.com. (
                     2019053101         ; Serial
                           3600         ; Refresh
                           1800         ; Retry
                         604800         ; Expire
                          43200 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

example.com.   IN      NS      ns1.mydnsprovider.com.
example.com.   IN      NS      ns2.mydnsprovider.com.
example.com.   IN      NS      ns3.mydnsprovider.com.

example.com.       IN      A       x.x.x.x

www     IN      A       x.x.x.x
                MX      10 example.com.  ; Primary Mail Exchanger
                TXT     "Example Systems S.L."


localhost       A       127.0.0.1

example.com.    A       x.x.x.x
host1           A       a.a.a.a
host2           A       b.b.b.b
...

ns1.mydnsprovider.com   IN      A       x.x.x.x
ns2.mydnsprovider.com   IN      A       y.y.y.y
ns3.mydnsprovider.com   IN      A       z.z.z.z
```

However when I do

```
dig @localhost example.com.
```

I do not obtain the additional records:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.59.amzn1 <<>> @ns1.mydnsprovider.com example.com.
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9999
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.           3600    IN      A       188.40.142.12

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.           3600    IN      NS      ns1.mydnsprovider.com.
example.com.           3600    IN      NS      ns2.mydnsprovider.com.
example.com.           3600    IN      NS      ns3.mydnsprovider.com.

;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 188.40.142.12#53(188.40.142.12)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun  7 11:00:07 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

The A records for 'mydnsprovider.com' are not shown.

I would like to know why and if this is the correct behavior for an authoritative server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's unclear what the actual goal is and it sounds like there could be an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) kind of thing going on here.

Addressing the things you bring up, though, the name `ns1.mydnsprovider.com.` is not part of the `example.com.` zone (it cannot be, by definition), and unless the same nameserver happens to also be authoritative for the `mydnsprovider.com` zone in addition to the `example.com` zone (which would be a coincidence, not at all a requirement) there is no reason why it would know anything about names such as `ns1.mydnsprovider.com.` or include data for them in the additional section (not required).

The records at the end of your `example.com` zone in the question would expand to `ns1.mydnsprovider.com.example.com.` etc, which is an entirely different name, with no relation to the name in the `NS` records. (Names without a trailing dot are considered relative.)

Comment: So basically these are not the type of records to be shown as "additional" and if the hosts at mydnsprovider.com are resolved successfully -as they are- then that's it, they must not be in example.com zone configuration. That's the answer I guess.

Comment: @JoseManuelGomezAlvarez Yes, pretty much.

Answer (score 6):

Since bind 9.2 (See the release notes [here](https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.12.0/RELEASE-NOTES-bind-9.12.0.pdf) bind defaults to the setting

```
minimal-responses no-auth-recursive;
```

Try setting that to

```
minimal-responses no;
```